# The method isEmpty(String) is undefined for the type StringUtils

Tags: java, string

When I am trying to use `isEmpty()`, I am getting the following error.

> The method isEmpty(String) is undefined for the type StringUtils

I am using Java 7, Eclipse Juno.

I manually added the Spring core-3.1.1 jar file too. But no luck.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: `isEmpty()` is a method of class `String` not `StringUtils`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you're using [`org.springframework.util.StringUtils`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html), which has no `isEmpty()`.

There is, however, an `isEmpty()` in [`org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html).

Ensure that you're using the correct `StringUtils`.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Yea I was importing " org.springframework.util.StringUtils".

Comment: that package does have isEmpty() it's right here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#isEmpty-java.lang.Object-

Answer (score 3):

However Question was Answered as expected long back, but I think one important point is a must to mention here (as now a days most of projects are  Maven based). So don't forget to add maven dependency for 'apache common lang' in your projects POM.xml before importing StringUtils for same. Else there wont be any import option.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Make sure you're importing the correct `StringUtils` as previously stated.

2) Make sure you're either doing a `import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isEmpty;` **OR** doing `StringUtils.isEmpty(myString);`

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation:

Deprecated. as of 5.3, in favor of hasLength(String) and hasText(String) (or ObjectUtils.isEmpty(Object))
Check whether the given object (possibly a String) is empty. This is effectively a shortcut for !hasLength(String).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#isEmpty-java.lang.Object-

Use one of the recommended methods instead. I don't recommend using **commons-lang** as it's an extra dependency.